# Rieman-Stieltjes integration "by parts"

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let us define a partition $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ of interval $[a,b]$ and let us define the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b fdg$ of a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$, or $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, as the limit, as the maximum of the leght of the partition intervals approaches 0, which must be independent from the partition chosen, of the Riemann-Stieltjes sum$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)[g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})]$$where $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i)$ and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function of bounded variation and continuous from the left$^1$. This is Kolmogorov and Fomin's definition in *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* (p. 362 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)). I know -thanks to [a very kind user of this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007183/coincidence-of-functions-defining-riemann-stieltjes-integral/1007586#1007586)- the following equality, where if one of the two integrals exists does the other one does too:$$\int_a^b fdg=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_a^bgdf$$

I have read a proof of the equality in Hille and Phillips' *Functional analysis and semi-groups*, but it uses two partitions such that $t_0=s_0=a$, $t_{n+1}=s_n=b$ and $t_i≤s_i≤t_{i+1}$ and the identity $\sum^n_{i=1}f(t_i)[g(s_i)−g(s_{i-1})]=f(t_{n+1})g(s_n)−f(t_0)g(s_0)−\sum^n_{i=0}g(s_i)[f(t_{i+1})−f(t_i)]$. I am not sure how to adapt a proof of this kind because

- $t_0,s_0,t_{n+1},s_n$ are set, while in Kolmogorov-Fomin's definition the limit of the Riemann-Stieltjes sum must be independent from the partition chosen;
- the arguments of the functions are allowed to be the right endpoints of the partition intervals.

My clumsy trial to modify Hille and Phillips' proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007183/coincidence-of-functions-defining-riemann-stieltjes-integral/1007586#comment2059170_1007586). How could the equality be proved to satisfy Kolmogorov and Fomin's definition of Riemann-Stieltjes integral? I do not even know whether Kolmogorov and Fomin's and Hille and Phillips' are equivalent for a real function of bounded variation. I thank anybody for any answer!!!

$^1$ Really, Kolmogorov and Fomin use $g:[a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous from the left and then set $g(b):=g(b^-)$, imposing that $g$ must be of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. Notwithstanding my efforts to understand why Kolmogorov and Fomin's definition of $g$ is not "$g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation and continuous from the left", I am convinced that theirs is equivalent to this last much more straightforward definition, which I therefore use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offered a first "solution" by mistakenly assuming $f$ was continuous from the left instead of $g$. I don't see how to show that the integrals are equivalent for a general $f$ and bounded variation $g$ normalized to be continuous on the left. The English translation of the 1968 second edition contains the standard definition of Riemann-Stieljes integral with evaluation points $t_{k}^{\star}\in[t_{k-1},t{k}]$, instead of one with evaluation points $t_{k}^{\star}\in [t_{k-1},t_{k})$. So I would suggest using the standard definition instead. The old definition for $\int_a^b f\,dg$ requires $g$ to be of bounded variation and normalized to be left continuous, and those assumptions are not needed for the general integral; and such assumptions prevent you from easily obtaining the general integration-by-parts theorem which would require both $f$ and $g$ to be of bounded variation in order to use their old definition.

I strongly suspect there must be a difference, or the Authors would not have changed the definition to the standard one. Of course, another compelling reason to change the definition is that general Riemann-Stieltjes integrals don't need to be restricted to the case where one of the functions is of bounded variation; so general normalization of $g$ in $\int_{a}^{b}f\,dg$ cannot be assumed without assuming left-hand limits exist everywhere. Such limits exist for functions of bounded variation, but--as I mentioned--that assumption is not needed to define the integral.

Their original definition appears to have been motivated out of trying to connect the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral with the Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. These two integrals are just not compatible. The Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral $\int_{a}^{b}f\,dg$ requires a measure $g$ coming from a function of bounded variation, while Riemann-Stieltjes does not require $g$ to be of bounded variation. Functions $f$ with discontinuities at an atom of $g$ can be integrated using Lesbesgue-Stieltjes, but this is not the case for the Riemann-Stieltjes $\int_{a}^{b}f\,dg$. These are significant differences, and there are others. So trying to closely wed the Riemann-Stieltjes definition to match Lebesgue-Stieltjes is not a good idea; even though it may help lead to Lebesgue-Stieltjes, the important generality of Riemann-Stieltjes is lost is the process. Any differences found when restricting to functions $g$ as you describe are likely to be related to the differences between Lebesgue-Stieltjes and Riemann-Stieltjes.

Comment: Thank you!!! You're really a great mathematician and a great person. I've found a proof of the general case in Hille-Phillips'. What I didn't know is that the two definitions are equivalent "because $g$ is assumed to be continuous from the left". That is a great result that allow me to understand why the original Russian text has that complicated definition of $g$ and the choice of $t_k^\star\in[t_{k-1},t_k)$ while the English translation "Introductory Real Analysis" has $g$ defined on $[a,b]$ and $t_k^\star\in[t_{k-1},t_k]$...

Comment: I intuitively grasp it, but how can we rigourously show that, by taking the limit, left-continuity allows us to take $t_k^\star$ at the endpoints? As to Hille and Phillips' proof (cfr. OP) $s_0=a$ and $s_n=b$ are set while, in order that $\int_a^b gdf$ exist one must be able to arbitrarily chose $g$'s arguments $s_0\in[t_0,t_1]$ and $s_n\in[t_n,t_{n+1}]$: what allows us to see that $\int_a^b gdf$ nevertheless? $\aleph_1$ thanks!

Comment: @DavideZena : Ooops. I scrambled the continuity requirements in my mind. Please uncheck as an answer. I was thinking $f$ was continuous from the left! That's why I was thinking that was a straightforward limit argument. It's not. I have to think more about this.

Comment: No, $g$ is continuous from the left in Kolmogorov-Fomin's definition. I intuitively "feel" that it implies that $t_n^\star$ can be chosen to be the right endpoint $t_n$, but I cannot manage to prove it with a rigourour calculation...

Comment: @DavideZena : Please uncheck my answer so that your question will continue to get good attention. In the meantime I'll think about how to present a correct argument.

Comment: I've asked a question on this specifical issue: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057365/two-definitions-of-the-riemann-stieltjes-integral